# Proof that restriction of $f$ to one-dimensional subspace is continuuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

$f$ is defined as:
$$ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$$
$$ 
f(x, y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if }(x, y) = (0, 0) \\
\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}, & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

I need to prove that for every one-dimensional subspace $$ D:= {\{\lambda(x_0, y_0): \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \}}$$ 
$f|_D$ is continuuous

The hint I received so far was that it would be helpful to show that a series $$(\lambda_n(x_0, y_0))$$ in $D$ converges in euclidian metric when $$(\lambda_n)$$ converges in $$\mathbb{R}$$ and vice versa.

But I don't really know how to show that and what to do next.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That's a strange hint. The restriction of $f$ to that line is the function$$\begin{array}{ccc}\lambda(x_0,y_0)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\\lambda&\mapsto&\displaystyle\frac\lambda{1+\lambda^2}\cdot\frac{x_0{y_0}^2}{{x_0}^2+{y_0}^4},\end{array}$$which is obviously continuous.

Comment: Thanks! The hint is cofusing for me... How did you come to the conclusion that \lambda is definied as you stated?

Comment: @thomas941 I don't understand your question. Perhaps that you meant to ask how did I get that expression for $f\bigl(\lambda(x_0,y_0)\bigr)$.

Comment: I meant, how did you find out that 'The restriction of f to that line is the function ->.......<- '

Comment: $$f\bigl((\lambda x_0,\lambda y_0)\bigr)=\dfrac{\lambda x_0(\lambda y_0)^2}{(\lambda x_0)^2+(\lambda y_0)^2}=\dfrac\lambda{1+\lambda^2}\cdot\frac{x_0{y_0}^2}{{x_0}^2+{y_0}^4}.$$

Comment: Could I also try it like here with polar coordinates? math.stackexchange.com/a/2012944/518930

Comment: @thomas941 I guess so.